# jquery hide show

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a table generated from database ( basically in MVC view). I want to make it editable. I want to use jquery to hide the row when edit button infront of row is clicked and show the row in edit format which is by default hidden. how can I do this using jquery?

Please suggest solution

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery Show

http://api.jquery.com/show/

JQuery Hide

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

You also may want to make use of div tables for this project instead of actual tables.  You selectors such as $("#idofcolumn").toggle(); to hide and show the div or in your case you would probably want to show a text field.  You could even .html() to replace the text in a column with a text box.  There are several ways to go about this.  Check out the JQuery documentation.

http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this by tagging the table row with a fake class name, then in the button click events I used jquery's Hide/Show.  Like this:

In your edit button click event call this:

```
$('.trMyRowIWantToHide').hide();
```

And tag your table row with a fake class like this:

```
<tr class="trMyRowIWantToHide">
```

Answer (score 0):

How exactly is the HTML set up for your rows?  Normally you could do $('SELECTOR').toggle() on each of them.

Comment: Do I need to make two views of each row. one is display mode and one is edit mode ?